# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package name>

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to install python modules in my raspberry pi 3B+ which is using Ubuntu Mate. For most of the modules i get the following error all the time

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

For instance, I tried the following code:

```
pip install functools_lru_cache

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting functools_lru_cache
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement functools_lru_cache (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for functools_lru_cache
```

It is not just this package but also `pip install backports` , `pip install soupsieve`, etc. Please Help !!!

Comment: NOOBS is just an installer, not a distribution. You've tagged the question Ubuntu, is that the distro you're running? Furthermore, I'm not aware of a package that goes by the name you mention, so that's probably why you get an error.

Comment: Thanks i update it.

Comment: A package named `functools_lru_cache` doesn't exist, `backports` is just a placeholder with nothing to install. `pip install soupsieve` should work; if it doesn't, please add the complete command output to the question.